# Read text from textbox in Coded UI Tests

Tags: winforms, coded-ui-tests

There is a bug/limitation in the Coded UI Test `WinEdit` class: when overriding the `OnKeyDown` method or subscribing to the `KeyDown` event in a text box, it is not possible to use the `WinEdit.Text` property.

That is, when you have this...

```
private void myTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

...this won't work:

```
var edit = new WinEdit(ancestor);
edit.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "myTextbox";
edit.Text = "New value"; // This doesn't work
```

I've found a work-around for setting the value [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsautotest/thread/224da6d4-47f3-44e6-a383-63b3e32bbfb4):

```
var edit = new WinEdit(ancestor);
edit.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "myTextbox";
Mouse.Click(edit);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("New value");
```

**My question:** does anyone know a work-around for reading the value?

```
var edit = new WinEdit(Window);
edit.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "myTextbox";
string actual = edit.Text; // This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a work-around myself:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;

var edit = new WinEdit(Window);
edit.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "myTextbox";
var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
SendMessage(edit.WindowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, sb.Capacity, sb);
string actual = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is :

Suppose you have one window form having one text box.

```
//Launch your Application
ApplicationUnderTest mainWindow = 
ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"D:\Samples\YourApplication.exe");

//Search Text box in your windows Form
var username = new WinWindow(mainWindow);
username.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "txtUserName";

//To Set Text or get, Initialize WinEdit object and asign searched object username to WinEdit object editUsername
WinEdit editUsername = new WinEdit(username) {Text = "Pakistan"};

//get text from textbox username
string text = editUserName.Text;
```

Thanks,