# Coded UI Tests: How can I set the search properties for recording?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I wanted to inform myself about Coded UI Tests. So I created some coded ui tests and played a bit around.

But now I'm at a point I can't help myself. I have the following problem. When I do record some actions from a dotNet 4.5 program, the recorder locates the forms, buttons, textfields and so on via **SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name]** That's definitely uncool.

Imagine you want to do an assertation on a text-control. The WinText.PropertyNames.Name would be the calculated value. So if you change some input values in the form which affect the calculation, the WinText.PropertyNames.Name will be changed to the new value and the coded ui test wont find the text-control with the changed value because it searched for the WinText.PropertyNames.Name of the control instead of the **WinText.PropertyNames.ControlName**.

**My Question is, is there a way to change the configuration of the standard search property the coded ui test builder uses to locate the needed objects?**

Because its a big effort to change this for every recorded object, afterwards.

PS: I'm not talking about the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\11.0\IEPropertyConfiguration.xml** which takes only effect on ie sites =)

## Additional:

**Lets make things clear:**

Here's my code:

```
public class UIItem100180Window : WinWindow
    {
        
        public UIItem100180Window(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "wert2Praemie12";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Any Title");
            #endregion
        }
        
        #region Properties
        public WinText UIItem100180Text
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItem100180Text == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItem100180Text = new WinText(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIItem100180Text.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "1.001,80";
                    this.mUIItem100180Text.WindowTitles.Add("Any Title");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIItem100180Text;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        
        #region Fields
        private WinText mUIItem100180Text;
        #endregion
    }
```

I got a **parent control(UIItem100180Window: WinWindow)** which creates my **Text-Control(UIITem100180Text: WinText)** on UI, that represents the value of my calculation. The problem is both have the same **.PropertyNames.ControlName** =).

That means if I'm going to add:

```
this.mUIItem100180Text.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "wert2Praemie12";
```

it will find alltime my parent-control: WinWindow. If I'm not adding it and if the value of the calculation changes (maybe calculation method was edited,..), and its not equal to **this.mUIItem100180Text.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "1.001,80";** the control wont be found and an errorMessage "..control not found" will be thrown.

**Later I will get problems at this line,** checking the Value of my text-control(WinText):

```
public void VerifyTextControl()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinText uIItem100180Text = this.xxx.UIItem100180Window.UIItem100180Text;
        #endregion

        // Verify that the 'DisplayText' property of '1.001,80' label equals '1.001,80'
        Assert.AreEqual("1.001,80", uIItem100180Text.DisplayText, "järhlich muss 1.001,80 € betragen!");
    }
```

my **uIItem100180Text:WinText** is handled as **WinWindow** because it finds only my parent-control when I'm searching for the PropertyNames.ControlName, like I said both got the same name. So I **can't use the .DisplayText-method**, and it ends in an error Message.

The best solution is, do your assertation on parent control, because it also keeps the value of the text-control and you wont have such problems like I had have.

Maybe this post is helpful for people who struggle at the same point.

**Note:**
UITestControl->WinControl->WinText
UITestControl->WinControl->WinWindow

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do it, but this article looks interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269469.aspx

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you believe is "uncool" and show why and how you might need to change it? In general if an application being tested is changed then the tests will also need to be changed to match. Otherwise the change was not a real change or the tests are inadequate.

Comment: thx jocke, i already read this article before (:

Comment: @AdrianHHH the problem is, if you want to check values and the value in the program changes somehow(e.g. to 2.000,98), it throws everytime a "control not found exception" instead an "assertfailedException". that my problem. Its logicaly because the control is located at the codeline:  this.mUIItem100180Text.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "1.001,80"; So it wont be found if the value changes and that pisses me off.

Comment: I have replied at link mentioned below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36649658/2871356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2: !! Problem solved !!**

Im gonna try to explain.

Heres our example:

```
public class UITextWindow : WinWindow
    {
        
        public UITextWindow(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "label1";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Form1");
            #endregion
        }
        
        #region Properties
        public WinText UITextText
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUITextText == null))
                {
                    this.mUITextText = new WinText(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUITextText.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "text";
                    this.mUITextText.WindowTitles.Add("Form1");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUITextText;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the coded ui test builder generates a **SearchProperty** to find our **Wintext UITextText**. But thats not needed because our Wintext UITextText **inherits** the needed property(ControlName) from **UITextWindow:WinWindow(parent)** in the cunstructor:

```
this.mUITextText = new WinText(this);
```

So theres no need to add an additional search property to find the child element, because both got the same controlName.

That prevents that the system throws an "..ElementNotFound"-Exception when the value of the Label changes. Instead we will get an "..AssertationFailure"-Exception, wich informs us that somethings wrong with the value of our label. Thats the standard way how it should work.

Just **delete** this line and everything will be fine:

```
this.mUITextText.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "text";
```

I dont know why the coded ui builder automatically adds this searchproperty to Labels to get us in trouble :/

**Update 1:**

**System.Windows.Forms.Label** is responsible for the troubles. If you do an assert on a label with coded ui tests and the value of the label changes one day, you will have the same problems like i have :/

Comment: I am having the same trouble with labels.  I have dynamic labels that do change at runtime.  I would like to assert against the value of the labels, but as soon as the Text property of the label changes, the control is NOT found.  I am just sure with your answer because you indicate I must edit the designer.cs and that is worrisome.  I do agree with you that the way labels are treated seems very unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure search properties, I hope this will help you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/10/coded-ui-test-configuring-search-properties-while-recording-on-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: Do not post link as answer instead make it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Through much pain and effort. I have to point this out don't ever touch the designer file it will be regenerated every time you tweak, add, remove functions or controls.

If you open the uimap file in your project (.uitest), it will show you all your captured controls and methods.
Right Click a control listed: 2 things to note. Rename(great for ugly dynamically controls)  **UIItem100180Text** also Properties.

In properties you can adjust Search And Filter properties
Search are prioretized over Filter
you can directly remove values that don't matter, add new criteria , remove values you want to exclude, or even switch the operator to ***Contains***

This should much more reliably fix your issue.

However if you have Dynamic Controls, this is where either in the normal cs file provided under the .uitest file, an extension method against the immediate parent control (cell->parent->table, button->parent->tab), or a capabilities layer (see http://www.slideshare.net/tharindaliyanage/coded-ui-hand-code-based-on-page-object-model) can be added.

For simplicity of this post for an Extension Method would look like

```
public static WinText GetSuperDynamicButton(this UITextWindow container, string displayText)
{
   var button = new WinText(container);
   button.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name]=displayText;
   //if you wanted to use the contains style 
   //button.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinText.PropertyNames.Name, displayText, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
   return button;
}
```